# Laravel reset password is generating 404 page error

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, i have a forget password system, when i click on forget password and and enter email id , i will recieve password reset link with token on email. But when i clicked on that link its going to 404 page. I have attached sample link which i recieved on email ( https://directory.lifeloveandotherthings.com/public/user/password/reset/1e15c30fcb769f14182cb407861b685bc31a8eb42121b6394049d979beda0753 ).

Following is my codes in routes (web.php)

```
Route::get('user/password/reset', 'User\UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('user/password/email', 'User\UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.reequest');
Route::post('user/password/reset', 'User\UserAuth\ResetPassswordController@reset')->name('password.email');
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'User\UserAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
```

Following is my code in ResetpasswordController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\UserAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JsValidator;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $redirectTo = '/user/home';

    protected $validationRules = [
                                        'name' => 'required|max:255',
                                        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
                                        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
                                    ];


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       // $this->middleware('user.guest');
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules,[],[],'#resetform');
        return view('user.auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email, 'validator' => $validator]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('users');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('user');
    }
}
```

In this resetpassword link controller i have just checked wether the calling is coming to `showResetForm`
Function by echo "hello" in that function, but still its returing 404 not found.

What is the problem here

Comment: Where this `route` call from

Answer (score 0):

Something I have run into with password resets is if you are still logged into your system it tries to hit the /home route. You might not have this route anymore and gives you

Answer (score 0):

You must have slashes or dots in the generated token and Laravel is   interpreting your token parameter as a route. Append this regex `[\w\s\-_\/\.\$]+` to your Password Reset Controller route and it will work again.
This is what I do to fix the problem

```
Route::get( '/user/reset/password/{token?}', 'CustomResetPasswordController@reset' )->where('token', '[\w\s\-_\/\.\$]+');
```